# Refactor orElseThrow block to return RuntimeException

Tags: java, java-8

I have got the below `findProductBetweenPriceRange()` method which throws `BadRequestException` as shown below:

```
public Product findProductBetweenPriceRange(int price1, int price2) {
    Optional<Product> product = productService.findProductBetween(price1, price2);
    return product.orElseThrow(() -> {
       String debugInfo = "price1="+price1+";price2="+price2;
       throw new BadRequestException("No Product found for price range",debugInfo);
    });
}
```

**BadRequestException class:**

```
public final class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {

    public BadRequestException(String errorMessage, String debugInfo) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.debugInfo = debugInfo;
    }

    //fields & getters
}
```

The above code works fine, but, I just wanted to refactor the `orElseThrow()` block to a different method as shown below.

I tried creating `throwBadRequestException()` method which `throws` `BadRequestException`  & I am calling it from `orElseThrow()`, 
but I am facing an error like **"no instance of type variable exists so that void conforms"**.

```
public Product findProductBetweenPriceRange(int price1, int price2) {
    Optional<Product> product = productService.findProductBetween(price1, price2);
    return product.orElseThrow(() -> throwBadRequestException(price1, price2));
}

private void throwBadRequestException(int price1, int price2) {
     String debugInfo = "price1="+price1+";price2="+price2;
     throw new BadRequestException("No Product found for price range", debugInfo);
}
```

I clearly know that `BadRequestException` is an unchecked exception so the compiler is not able to find that the method throws the required exception. Just to double check, I also tried to add the `BadRequestException` using `throws` clause to the method signature to hint the compiler, but no luck.

So, the question is that is there any way that I can refactor `orElse` block nicely to a separate method and throw the `RuntimeException` (i.e., `BadRequestException`) ?

Comment: return an exception instance from your helper, then throw that

Comment: replace `throw` with `return`, and `void` to `BadRequestException`.

Comment: `orElseThrow` expects the `Supplier` to return the exception, not for it to be thrown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So just `return` the `BadRequestException` and you are done. 
The `void` is basically causing the issue. `orElseThrow` takes a supplier, not a function.

So, you need to modify the code as below:

```
public Product findProductBetweenPriceRange(int price1, int price2) {
   Optional<Product> product = productService.findProductBetween(price1, price2);
   return product.orElseThrow(() -> throwBadRequestException(price1, price2));
}

private BadRequestException throwBadRequestException(int price1, int price2) {
   String debugInfo = "price1="+price1+";price2="+price2;
   return new BadRequestException("No Product found for price range", debugInfo);
}
```

Comment: I verified that even `throw new BadRequestException` also works. So edited and added a comment justifying that.

Comment: There's no point in manually throwing the exception that `orElseThrow` will throw anyways. The first part of your answer is OK, the edit, while it works, is not a good use of the API. (I upvoted anyways because the first part is correct).

Comment: Thanks!that point is taken and agree second one is not a good practice as you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

In `Java-8` you can use [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) to do it.

```
private BiFunction<String, String, BadRequestException> badReqExceptionSupplier = (msg, info) -> new BadRequestException(msg, info);
```

Use it as below :

```
throw badReqExceptionSupplier.apply("No Product found for price range",debugInfo);
```